# Memmove is overlapping

Tags: c

I'm using `memmove()`, but it seems that the destination is overwriting the source or maybe I do not understand what overwriting is. I have the array of `char` (the destination) and then a pointer to the destination, that is inside the vector.

```
char destination[]="abcdefg";
char * source = destination+3;
```

The source is  `"defg"`. Then I use `memmove()` to move four characters and print the source. When I look at the source, it has changed to `"gefg"`.

```
printf("%s\n",memmove(destination,source,sizeof(char)*4));
printf("%s",source);
```

I thought that `memmove()` should prevent the overwriting, or maybe I am not understanding.

Comment: Maybe you should look at destination, not at the source (which is still dest+3). (NOTE: `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition)

Comment: `memmove` means to copy bytes even if the regions overlap

Comment: Yes, im sorry , is overwriting not overlapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`memmove` allows the source and destination to have an overlapping region, and it is defined so that the contents of the source before `memmove` will compare equal to contents of the destination after the `memmove`.

If the source and destination overlap, you will expect the source to have changed in some way after the `memmove` call. What is prevented is the possible corruption of destination.

The behavior of `memmove(dst, src, len)` will be similar to:

```
char buf[len];
memcpy(buf, src, len);
memcpy(dst, buf, len);
```

But the implementation is optimized to make only a single pass, rather than two.